# How to make a remote server be invisible to a web user

Tags: web, architecture

I have a webserver `www.example.com` that takes user input and calculates results on a remote server
`<form action="www2.example.com/action.cgi">`

Now the user is on the second server. How do I keep the user on the main server (or make `www2` invisible to the user)?

One possibility is to do an Ajax query in the background, but that would mean results are transferred from `www2` to `www` and then to the user, which adds delay and bandwidth costs.

What are some possibilities to accomplish this?

Also, if, in future, we have multiple remote servers `www2`, `www3`, etc. what would be the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks so much!

Comment: In general what you seem to want to avoid is exactly what people usually do; have a web site front-end contact one or more back-end servers to do processing and then return the results. Bandwidth is between front and backend is usually not charged and added latency negligible for typical web purposes

Comment: Every web site above a certain level of traffic already does this.

Comment: Google is, of course, different, and we can probably not implement what they do, but when I search on Google, they do whatever magic on the backend and return the results on google.com